# Who has tweeted the most about a given text?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, twitter

first question in StackOverflow, so please be gentle on me.

### Situation:

I have got a mySQL table with about 14000 lines containing tweets from various users on Twitter. It contains the columns:

- username
- user_id
- time_of_tweet
- tweet_text
- geo_position

... and other info too, which is not relevant in regards to this question.

### Problem:

I would like to know which user has written a distinct word (e.g. "volkswagen") the most. That is to say: Who has tweeted the most about a given string of text?

I figured out I needed to do `COUNT()` and `SELECT DISTINCT` in some way, but no matter how I put my code, I get an SQL-error. I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Sth like `SELECT user_id FROM mytable WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%volkswagen%' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%volkswagen%'` to filter tweets with `volkswagen`:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM your_table
WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%volkswagen%'
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 1;              -- this will be nondeterministic if 2 users has the same number
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2be2e5/1/0)**</kbd>

For better performance you should consider using full-text index.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(
    username VARCHAR(100),
    user_id INT,
    tweet_text VARCHAR(140)
    -- ...
    );

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx ON your_table(tweet_text) ;  

SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM your_table
WHERE MATCH(tweet_text) AGAINST('volkswagen')
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50ade/2/0)**</kbd>